# how to find out if a serie is sorted using pointers in c

Tags: c, function-pointers

i have the following program in c lanquage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_sorted ( int *array , int num , int prev , int *index);

int main ()
{
    int N;
    int i;
    int prev;
    int data[100];
    bool flag;


    printf("Enter length:\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("Enter %d integers:\n" ,N);
    for (i =0; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&data[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter previous number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&prev);


    int *index= NULL;

    flag = is_sorted(data,N,prev,index);

    if ( !flag )
    {
        printf("%d ", *index);
    }
}

bool is_sorted ( int *array , int num , int prev , int *index) 
{
    if ( prev > array[0] ) 
    {
        index=prev;
        return false;
    }

    for ( int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        if ( array[i] > array[i+1] )
        {
            index = array[i];
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The function is_sorted takes as input an array of integers and another one random integer and returns true if prev < array[0] < array[1] < ... < array[n].

I am using a pointer in order to find which is the first element to spoil the serie's order but i am a little bit confused with pointer's syntax.

Running it i am getting the following results:

```
pointers.c:43:14: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   43 |         index=prev;
      |              ^
pointers.c:51:19: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   51 |             index = array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

`index` is a pointer to an integer.  You need to dereference the pointer to assign to the variable that it points to in the caller.

```
*index = prev;
...
*index = array[i];
```